# Scikit-learn installation - Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip

I am running `pip3 install -U scikit-learn` to install Scikit-learn however it returns an error:

```
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/ks/4ncxyk05129fd_qqs3s5y6v00000gn/T/tmpjur9qur6
       cwd: /private/var/folders/ks/4ncxyk05129fd_qqs3s5y6v00000gn/T/pip-install-a7o70faj/scikit-learn_2ee6feb334cf42fcae6b0bc63f18e9fb
  Complete output (143 lines):
  Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
  C compiler: clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g
```

What can I do to fix this in order to sucessfully install Scikit-learn?

Answer (score 5):

it worked for me.
you can see for more information here.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#install-bleeding-edge

```
    pip install --pre --extra-index https://pypi.anaconda.org/scipy-wheels- 
    nightly/simple scikit-learn
```